# NicEdit + Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide, nicedit

Lately me and my QA buddies are trying to find a way to make Selenium IDE (v2.2 with FireFox v22) type a text into NicEdit's textarea, but without success.
We took a look on the internet for the past few days, and so far we discovered, among other things, that NiceEdit is not an iFrame (I think many here already know that).
We're not using code nor any other webdrive, just Selenium IDE, which makes things a bit harder, I guess.
We've tried xpath, class, id etc... no success.
But in these cases, the Find button in Selenium highlights the area.

So, is there a way to make Selenium IDE type in the NiceEdit's textarea without code?
Here's the html code of NicEdit's textarea provided by FireBug.

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="span12 " data-bind="html: Conteudo" id="conteudo"     style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</div>
```

And the rest before it:

```
<div id="editorPanel" style="width: 100%;" unselectable="on">
    <div class=" nicEdit-panelContain" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);" unselectable="on">
        <div class=" nicEdit-panel" style="margin: 0px 2px 2px; overflow: hidden;" unselectable="on">
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="conteudo" class="span12" contenteditable="true" data-bind="html: Conteudo"> 
</div>
```

EDIT: I've found out that NicEdit turns the textarea into a div, so Selenium is not able to focus on the area.
Anyone has any sugestions about how can I make Selenium put some text on NicEdit?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>this.browserbot.findElement(&quot;id=someID&quot;).innerHTML='fillerText'</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Does the above work for you?